# Stacking fluid height divs

Tags: css, html

I might be having a serious brain fart here but I can't seem to accomplish what I want to accomplish using divs and css. What I am trying to do is create a wrapper that fills the initial viewport view 100% then put more content underneath. If I was doing it in tables it would look roughly like this:

```
<table height="100%">
<tr height="10%">
<td>Blank</td>
</tr>
<tr height="15%">
<td>Section 1</td>
</tr>
<tr height="25%">
<td>Section 2</td>
</tr>
<tr height="50%">
<td>Section 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
Look here is more content under where the viewport is
```

I have fiddled around using divs trying to accomplish this and I really want to avoid using a table for a layout (no thanks 2001) but has anyone accomplished this using just css and divs (no javascript)?

Comment: Do you have any CSS from your previous attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to set the height of the body to 100%?

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body { height:100%; }
#div1 { height:10%; background:red; }
#div2 { height:15%; background:green; }
#div3 { height:25%; background:red; }
#div4 { height:50%; background:green; }
```

[Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/84TUy/).

You could of course achieve the same results with absolute or fixed positioning, but this is the clean and simple equivalent of your sample.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to set `html, body` to `height: 100%`

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="one"></div>    
   <div class="two"></div>    
   <div class="three"></div>    
   <div class="four"></div>        
</div>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</p>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.container{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

.one{
  height: 10%;
  background:red;
}

.two{
  height: 15%;
  background:green;
}

.three{
 height: 25%;
 background:black;
}

.four{
 height: 50%;
 background:yellow;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JDj4G/)